# Change items bool property in a collection if they match/not match the index containing in other list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an `IEnumerable` `Collection` of `Model` which contains around 70 items.

```
Model myModel = new Model()
{
    Index = 1,
    IsSelected = false
}
```

I have another `List<int> Indexes` which may contains integers matching any of the `Model`s Index in the first `Collection`. `List<int> Indexes` can also be empty but not `NULL`.

```
List<int> Indexes = new List<int>() { 3, 21, 33, ...};
```

I managed to change the `IsSelected` property to `true` for any matching index using

```
collection.Where(col => Indexes.Any(index => col.Index == index))
.ToList()
.ForEach(a => { a.IsSelected = true; });
```

But how do I set `IsSelected` to false for items with index that's NOT present in `List<int> Indexes` using LINQ?

If possible I would like to combine those set to `true` and set to `false` LINQ statements in one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.Where(m => !Indexes.Contains(m.Index)).ForEach(m => { m.IsSelected = false; });
```

If you want to set them in one statement.

```
collection.ForEach(m => { m.IsSelected = Indexes.Contains(m.Index); });
```

Comment: Thanks. If it's possible I would like to combine those statements setting to `true` and `false`. See my updated question.

Comment: Your code wouldn't work. ForEach isn't available for IEnumerables.

Comment: sure - add a ToList after where or I was assuming collection was a list

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
collection.ToList().ForEach(col => { 
      col.IsSelected = Indexes.Contains(col.Index); 
});
```